# How to restore a single mongodb database with oplogReplay?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I'm having trouble finding if this is even a supported operation. I found things that suggest it didn't use to be, but I'm not getting any logs that indicate it's not supported (just confusing logs) and I wasn't able to find anything in mongo's docs that indicate it's not allowed.

For reference:

- OS: Centos6.6
- Mongod: v3.0.2
- Mongo Shell: v3.0.2
- Mongodump: v3.0.2
- Mongorestore: v3.0.2

Here's the command I'm running to create my dump (I am using auth):

```
mongodump -u username -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --oplog
```

Here's the original file structure after a dump.

```
└── dump
    ├── oplog.bson
    ├── admin
    │   ├── system.users.bson
    │   ├── system.users.metadata.json
    │   ├── system.version.bson
    │   └── system.version.metadata.json
    ├── dogs
    │   ├── tails.bson
    │   └── tails.metadata.json
    └── mydata
        ├── objects.bson
        ├── objects.metadata.json
        ├── fs.chunks.bson
        ├── fs.chunks.metadata.json
        ├── fs.files.bson
        ├── fs.files.metadata.json
        ├── configuration.bson
        └── configuration.metadata.json
```

I've tried a few different variations of restore to get what I want, but they each seem a little off. After reading the following in mongo's docs concerning mongorestore:

> --db does not control which BSON files mongorestore restores. You must use the mongorestore path option to limit that restored data.

it seems to me that I should be able to copy the oplog.bson into the particular database's folder that I want to restore and then run the following from inside dump/:

```
mongorestore -u username -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --oplogReplay --db dogs dogs
```

I found this confusing because it gives these logs:

```
2015-05-13T22:10:12.694+0000    building a list of collections to restore from dogs dir
2015-05-13T22:10:12.695+0000    reading metadata file from dogs/tails.metadata.json

2015-05-13T22:10:12.695+0000    restoring dogs.oplog from file dogs/oplog.bson
2015-05-13T22:10:12.696+0000    no indexes to restore
2015-05-13T22:10:12.696+0000    finished restoring dogs.oplog

2015-05-13T22:10:12.696+0000    restoring dogs.tails from file dogs/tails.bson
2015-05-13T22:10:12.697+0000    restoring indexes for collection dogs.tails from metadata
2015-05-13T22:10:12.697+0000    finished restoring dogs.tails

2015-05-13T22:10:12.697+0000    replaying oplog
2015-05-13T22:10:12.697+0000    no oplog.bson file in root of the dump directory, skipping oplog application

2015-05-13T22:10:12.697+0000    done
```

The first part about dogs.oplog makes it seem as if things are working, however the later message about oplog confuses me.

No matter which variations of directories and paths that I try I can't seem to satiate this message in particular:

```
2015-05-13T22:10:12.697+0000    replaying oplog
2015-05-13T22:10:12.697+0000    no oplog.bson file in root of the dump directory, skipping oplog application
```

Does this mean my oplog replay isn't happening? Is my point-in-time backup / restore still doing what I expect? I recall seeing some tickets about improving the log messages of mongotools, perhaps this is just poor logging?

Comment: Do not nail me down on that, but iirc since you explicitly told to restore ` dogs` , the dogs directory of your dump becomes the root of the restore operation. So the oplog for dogs is adopted from the existing ` oplog.bson`, but since there is no file of such name under dogs, no replay happens for that file.

Comment: I did copy the oplog.bson into the dogs directory first and still received the logs above

Comment: Strange behaviour, but since the oplog reply from `dogs/oplog.bson` was reported to be successful, I wouldn't worry. You could inspect the oplog manually and check out wether the operations in there are applied

Comment: Is the end result of this question "don't worry about that error message"?  I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: there already is one: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-953 it's never been supported to use oplogReplay for anything but the full instance restore.

Comment: and the oplog was not *replayed* it was restored - there is now an oplog collection in your dogs DB, which is not at all what you wanted.